# How can I send a request for thousands of fares at once and receive back a single file?

Tags: sabre

I apologize in advance for not having very much experience in this sort of thing. I came to sabre looking for the following functionality:

1. I have a list of 500 cities
2. These cities need to be visited by one of 10 offices (located in 10 cities)
3. The cities must be visited in a window of 10 days.
4. What is the lowest cost way of visiting these 500 cities?

To get a fare for all of these scenarios would require 50,000 inquires (property 1, office 1, day 1; property 2, office 1, day 1 etc.)

Since I obviously don't want to individually input each of these searches, is there a way this can all be done at once?

I think the "advanced calendar" search gets me somewhere when it comes to the date range but like I said my experience is limited and I would like to know if what I need is even possible before I start to go down this path.

Thank you very much anything helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely an option to consider as you mention with Advanced Calendar.

Another option consider is receiving the feed from Market Fare View. There is an example and more information below.

https://developer.sabre.com/informational_services/market_fare_view